# Understand Klocwork bitwise operation sign

Tags: c, bit-shift, klocwork

When analysed by klocwork, the following line

```
pTxData[index] =  ( UINT8_C(0) << UINT8_C(4) );
```

gives error

> Operand of bitwise operation has type 'signed char' instead of
>   'unsigned integer'

I already reduced the problem to the minimum by removing any `#define` and have absolutely no clue why this can happen.

Comment: `UINT8_C` seems to be a macro. What does it do?

Comment: @P.W See e.g. [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those unaware, `UINT8_C` is a C standard macro<sup>1)</sup> for getting an integer constant of type `uint_least8_t` rather than the default `int`.

Thus `UINT8_C(0)` is equivalent to `(uint_least8_t)0`. This will be a small integer type. And as such it is subject to integer promotion<sup>2)</sup> when passed on as left operand to `<<`. After promotion it ends up as type `int`, equivalent to just writing `0`.

You should never use signed operands with bitwise operators, so this is the core reason for the error message. Corrected code should look like `0u << 4`. Although this code is of course pointless for anything except self-documenting code. (And of course shifting the value 0 is always harmless.)

Using `UINT8_C`on the right operand of `<<` is nonsense - that operand does not partake in any type promotion of the result. If you need to use unsigned literals just to sate a coding standard, then use `4u`. Notably, standards like MISRA-C do *not* require `u` suffix in cases where you actually don't need an unsigned type - this is a common source of false positives from tools.

Summary - use this:

```
pTxData[index] =  0u << 4;
```

In addition, Klockwork is giving an incorrect diagnostic message. The operators in your expression are both likely equivalent to `unsigned char` and definitely not `signed char` like the tool says.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Introduced in C99 [7.18.4.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.18.4.1).

<sup>2)</sup> See [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Answer (score 1):

In most expressions integer types of rank smaller than that of `int` get converted into `int` (if `int` can represent all values without a loss) or `unsigned int` (otherwise).

To simplify it a bit, consider the rank to correspond to the number of bits in the type, the more bits, the higher the rank (for a definitive treatment of the term, see a language reference (e.g. you may start [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion))).

And it seems to be the case here, the type returned by `UINT8_C()` (possibly `unsigned char` in disguise) has smaller rank than `int` and so you end up having a signed type.

Now, the reason for the warning is that shifting signed integer types is not well defined in all cases. Shifting negative values left or overflowing while shifting amounts to *undefined behavior*, meaning the program may misbehave in a wide variety of ways if either of those two conditions is encountered. (It's legal to overflow when shifting unsigned types, you get a truncated value).

Also, the shift count can't be negative.

However, if this is the exact code, the warning is unnecessary because it should be obvious that shifting 0 left by 4 positions is completely safe. If you used variables instead of constants, the compiler (or the tool) would not always be able to deduce safety of this shift and in that case you should pay attention to the warning and rewrite your code in such a way that there would be neither undefined behavior nor warning.